# Remove characters in a specific column before a specific character

Tags: sed, awk

I have a file that looks like so:

```
chr22   43089055    43089055    -   NM_017436   C   300 903delC
chr22   43089715-43089717   43089715-43089717   -   NM_017436   CTT 79
```

I want to remove all the characters before the `-` in column 3 to give me an output as depicted below:

```
chr22   43089055    43089055    -   NM_017436   C   300 903delC
chr22   43089715-43089717   43089717    -   NM_017436   CTT 79
```

I've used `awk '{$2+=0}1' file` in the past to remove characters after the `-`, but I don't believe I can use this same technique for my current problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -lane 'BEGIN { $, = "\t" } $F[2] =~ s/.*-//; print @F' < file
```

- `-l` appends newlines to `print`
- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-a` splits each line on whitespace and populates the `@F` array
- `$,` separates list members when printed, set it to tab
- `s/.*-//` substitutes everything up to a dash with nothing, it's bound to the third column (arrays are indexed from 0)

Answer (score 3):

As some different variants

1. **awk**

   `awk '{$3=A[split($3,A,"-")]}1' file`
2. **sed**

   `sed -r 's/((\S+\s+){2})[^- ]+-/\1/' file`

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
< input awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="   "} {gsub(/[^-]*-/, "", $3); print}'
```